# Goodbye, Affable Geek

Tags: discussion, users, in-memoriam

I have just learned that one of our fellow users, Affable Geek, [died this past Valentines Day](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4496/lets-take-a-moment-to-remember-affable-geek).  His real name was Michael Hollinger, and he was only 43 years old.  He was on SF&F the day before he passed away, and he even commented on Christianity.SE the day he died:

> This is exactly the kind of question this site was designed for. Thank you!!!!

I think I can safely say that the collective good wishes and condolences of the entire SF&F community go out to his family.  We would be fortunate to have more people like him on this site.

Comment: Should we (well, mods) edit his profile to note that he's deceased?

Answer (score 20):

[**Boat drinks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Things_to_Do_in_Denver_When_You%27re_Dead).

/slytherincess raises her glass

<sub>I linked "Boat drinks" to the wiki page for *Things to Do in Denver When You're Dead*. I meant this to explain the source/meaning of "Boat drinks" in the context of a death, but it didn't occur to me that the title of the movie itself would make linking to it possibly super tacky. Please know that was not my intention at all. "Boat drinks" is what I've always posted when there's been a death. **Affable Geek** was a great user to interact and trade comments with. I'm truly sorry to hear that he's passed. :(</sub>